# Connect Float output to Float input causes an error

Tags: animation-nodes

[image: node setup]

[image: node setup error]

I am playing around with animation nodes, so I have a bunch of instances along a spline. As you see in the working node tree, instances 31.00 and a Math node socket B also set as 31.00.

So now you think, OK I'll drive the math value by the number of instances, which would be the same float number. Wrong! If you do this everything goes RED and the whole world is destroyed!!!

Why can I not connect these two nodes?

Comment: does it help you when you look into the problems panel on the left? the problem is not the datatype but that you connect two different networks which cannot be merged.

Comment: Ah yes of course now i understand. I correct to new parameter in my loop subprogram and now it works.

Comment: perfect, would you like to write a full answer for your question yourself?

Comment: Maybe you should not allow connections of this type rather than just making everything go red and leaving it connected?

Comment: I prefer the way it is now because it's better to show an error message instead of just not allowing you to make this links (I'm not even able to forbid this with python!). It also helps to grasp the concept of networks in AN earlier. One thing I want to change is that you are told to look into the problems panel directly in Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Jacques, in the problems panel we can see what has caused this issue. I highlighted this in red.

[image: problems panel]

What I needed to do was to use another socket on the subprogram and loop input nodes, I have also highlighted these in red on the node tree.

[image: node tree]

Finally here is what the node tree produces, nothing spectacular but at least I'm learning how to use the amazing Animation Nodes addon.

[image: animation]

Comment: one quick tip: you don't have to pass the length of the lists you iterate over separately. You can also just use the "Iterations" socket in the Loop Input node. It should give you the same effect in your animation.

Comment: Thank you, this saves me passing values through. I will pick these things up over time.